# Does curl consider scheme protocol as permitted?

Tags: linux, curl

The documentation about the [curl](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) say that:

> --proto
>
> Tells curl to limit what protocols it may use in the transfer. [...]
>
> - Permit this protocol **in addition** to protocols **already permitted** (this is the default if no modifier is used).

In the following command, I'm wondering if the ftps protocol will be the only protocol used or if the ftp will also be considered as "permitted" since it's specified as a scheme in the url.  If both protocol are consider, which one will have the priority?

```
curl -p "ftp://ftp.example.com/" --proto ftps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `--proto` does. It does not change the protocol, it simply disallows certain protocols. From the [manpage](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html):

> Tells curl to limit what protocols it may use in the transfer. Protocols are evaluated left to right, are comma separated, and are each a protocol name or 'all', optionally prefixed by zero or more modifiers. Available modifiers are:
>
> + Permit this protocol in addition to protocols already permitted (this is the default if no modifier is used).
>
> - Deny this protocol, removing it from the list of protocols already permitted.
>
> = Permit only this protocol (ignoring the list already permitted), though subject to later modification by subsequent entries in the comma separated list.

If the protocol you choose in the URL isn't permitted, then an error will be thrown:

```
$ curl -p "http://example.com/" --proto -http
curl: (1) Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

If the protocol is permitted (which it is by default), then it will use **that** protocol and that protocol **only**, not any of the other permitted protocols.

This is mainly useful for when you're using curl in an application and you want safety:

```
curl (user provided url)
```

is bad because then the user can enter in some more sensitive protocols like `scp://` or `gopher://`. So, you would do something like

```
curl --proto =http,https (user provided url)
```

to limit the requests to http and https only.